# Null values for one custom field

Tags: trigger, bulkification, null

I have below trigger block. I am getting null values for `dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c`.

```
if(Trigger.isbefore && (Trigger.isInsert|| Trigger.isUpdate)){
        System.debug(':::::inside Isbefore::::');
            for(Deal_Support_Request_del__c dsrl : Trigger.new){
                System.debug(':::::inside for loop::::'+Trigger.new);
                System.debug(':::::inside for loop::::');
                System.debug(':::::value of recurrence::::'+recurrence);
                System.debug(':::::value of recordtype::::'+dsrl.recordTypeID);
                System.debug(':::::value of opp id ::::'+dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__c);
                System.debug(':::::value of business group::::'+dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c);
                if(!recurrence && (dsrl.RecordtypeId == dsrSORequestRecordTypeId) && dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c=='Ultrasound'){
                dsrl.GTM_Region__c='';
                System.debug(':::::value of GTM::::'+dsrl.GTM_Region__c);
                }}
```

The value of "dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__c" is coming correctly as id but for dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c it is giving null values.When i queried in soql using below query i am able to get values.

```
SELECT Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c FROM Deal_Support__c where id='a0S7A000000dT9r'
```

Comment: Your SOQL is working off  'Deal_Support__c' while your trigger.new() is over 'Deal_Support_Request_del__c'. Are you mixing up objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in related objects (like your case, `dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c`) is not available in trigger context variables.

Assuming that this code is called via a trigger on `Deal_Support_Request_del__c`, `dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__c` is available because that is a field on your `Deal_Support_Request_del__c` object.

`dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c`, on the other hand, is related data. It's the `Business_Group__c` field on what I assume is the `Opportunity` object.

To get `dsrl.Related_Opportunity_del__r.Business_Group__c` (a field on a record *related to a record on the object your trigger is on*), you'll need to perform a query.